# "It was nothing" vs "it wasn't anything"

Tags: expression-choice

How do native English speakers decide when to use the former or the later?

Example:

> No, **it was nothing** official. She just *stopped* coming to work.
>
> No, **it wasn't anything** official. She just *stopped* coming to work.

For some reason, *"it was nothing official"* has [6](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22it%20was%20nothing%20official%22&oq=%22it%20was%20nothing%20official%22&gs_l=serp.4...61819.62214.0.62258.3.3.0.0.0.0.157.279.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..3.0.0.zMqkgSA721s) hits on Google Books and *"it wasn't anything official"* has [79](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22it%20wasn%27t%20anything%20official%22&oq=%22it%20wasn%27t%20anything%20official%22&gs_l=serp.3...23286.25411.0.25555.14.11.0.0.0.0.246.959.0j6j1.7.0....0...1.1.64.serp..13.1.130.tZfBjkYF9yw). This makes me wonder, when *"it was nothing"* is preferred over *"it wasn't anything"*?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I doubt the average native speaker "decides" whether to use ***nothing,*** ***anything,*** or *nothing at all* (i.e. - *No, it wasn't official*). But I'm not even sure this is particularly a matter of *English* established idiomatic preference, given that French and Spanish have ***de rien*** and ***de nada*** corresponding to ***It was nothing*** *(= Don't mention it)*. But arguably *claiming* something is "nothing" is more direct/simpler than *denying* that it's "anything".

Comment: @FumbleFingers "...claiming something is "nothing" is more direct/simpler than denying that it's "anything." Yes, I also thought about that, and that's why I'm surprised about the Google Books results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*[There was nothing official](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22there%20was%20nothing%20official%22&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=bks&ei=pNkCVsXOKsKPU5m8g3g&start=30&sa=N&dpr=1)*" vs. "*[there wasn't anything official](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=bks&q=%22there%20wasn%27t%20anything%20official%22&oq=%22there%20wasn%27t%20anything%20official%22&gs_l=serp.12...4926.7159.0.9488.7.7.0.0.0.0.169.1041.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..5.2.316.4IL55_IqM5M)*" will get you more results on Google Books, respectively  633 and 35. But I think the expression you're looking for is:

> There was no official announcement. She just stopped coming to work.

[image]